# Send password to service from Outlook

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

Hi i have Outlook plugin that send request to my WCF Service. I faced with some issues regarding public folders. So the one way to resolve it to save user Account and Password inside plugin configuration (saved in system registry key). What is the safe way to save it and send it to server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CryptProtectData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380261(v=vs.85).aspx) and store the data in file or registry. The data can be decrypted using [CryptUnprotectData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380882(v=vs.85).aspx). The data is encrypted in such a way that only the user with the same credentials can decrypt the data, i.e. it cannot be decrypted from another computer or when running in a secury context of a diffent Windows user.

Microsoft itself uses these functions to store credentials for the POP3/IMAP4/SMTP accounts in Outlook.

Comment: Thanks you for your suggestion. I tested it and it works fine. But as i understand i can use it only in same pc ... So what about part where i send request to WCF Service? Or i can send it in string property to wcf service and wcf will secure it?

Comment: If you specify the CRYPTPROTECT_LOCAL_MACHINE flag, the data can be decrypted from under any user account on that machine, but it still has o be the same machine. What are you trying to protect? The password storage that will be used later? Or protecting the password and having it decrypted on another machine?

Comment: I'm tring to protect password and decrypt in on another machine for use it there for impersonate Office365 user

Comment: But where will the password will be stored in a file or a registry value? That is where CryptProtectData  is supposed to be used. To protect the data in transmission, you'd need too use something different.